# What am I missing here? Node, Express, req.files['image0']

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to pull the data out of the req.files array but the dot notation isn't working and I don't understand what I'm missing.

My Pug set Up:

```
if product.image
   .col-lg-1.pull-left
       img.product-img(src='/images/' + product.image, alt=product.title)
   .col-lg-11.pull-right
       input(type="hidden", name="mainImg", value=product.image)
       input.form-control(type="file", name="image0", id="image0")
   .clear
else
    .col-lg-11.pull-right
        input.form-control(type="file", name="image0", id="image0" value="")
```

This returns the req.files array as expected:

```
console.log(req.files)
```

result:

```
{ image0:
   [ { fieldname: 'image0',
   originalname:'Some_image.jpg',
   encoding: '7bit',
   mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
   destination: 'images',
   filename: 'bdad727257698479d84157ad0211b05f.jpg',
   path: 'images\\bdad727257698479d84157ad0211b05f.jpg',
   size: 109205 } ],
  image1:
   [ { fieldname: 'image1',
   originalname:'Some_image.jpg',
   encoding: '7bit',
   mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
   destination: 'images',
   filename: '9546c3810ad9d6c471fde641a30078fd.jpg',
   path: 'images\\9546c3810ad9d6c471fde641a30078fd.jpg',
   size: 109205 } ],
  image2:
   [ { fieldname: 'image2',
   originalname:'Some_image.jpg',
   encoding: '7bit',
   mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
   destination: 'images',
   filename: '0bd6d9da3b53348f5b9145723d4da340.jpg',
   path: 'images\\0bd6d9da3b53348f5b9145723d4da340.jpg',
   size: 78420 } ]
 } '#################'
```

This returns the first array element as expected:

```
console.log(req.files['image0'], '#################')
```

result:

```
[ { fieldname: 'image0',
originalname: 'Some_Image_Name.jpg',
encoding: '7bit',
mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
destination: 'images',
filename: '28efd1e7544820acc0ac174ac8404ea9.jpg',
path: 'images\\28efd1e7544820acc0ac174ac8404ea9.jpg',
size: 109205 } ] '#################'
```

This returns undefined and I don't understand why:

```
console.log(req.files['image0'].fieldname)
```

Here is my multer setup:

```
const upload = multer({dest: 'images', storage: imgStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter });
// app.use(upload.array('image'));

app.use(upload.fields([
    {
          name: 'image0', maxCount: 1
    },
    {
          name: 'image1', maxCount: 1
    },
    {
          name: 'image2', maxCount: 1
    },
    {
          name: 'image3', maxCount: 1
    }
])
```

I eventually want to set up a loop to iterate through a possible 20 or more pictures but I want to get the data first before I try to tackle a loop like that. This project is for a multi-image upload where the images are not overwritten if there is no image data passed and if data is passed only the image specified is overwritten. That is why I'm using upload.fields instead of .any() or array().

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Image0 prop is array not an object here...try console.log(req.files['image0'][0].fieldname)

Comment: Change `console.log(req.files['image0'].fieldname)` to `console.log(req.files['image0'][0].fieldname)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access a property of an array as if it's an object. This is invalid Javascript.

Try: `req.files['image0'][0].fieldname`

`req.files['image0']` returns:

```
[ { fieldname: 'image0',
originalname: 'Some_Image_Name.jpg',
encoding: '7bit',
mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
destination: 'images',
filename: '28efd1e7544820acc0ac174ac8404ea9.jpg',
path: 'images\\28efd1e7544820acc0ac174ac8404ea9.jpg',
size: 109205 } ]
```

Which is an array.

`req.files['image0'][0]` returns:

```
{ fieldname: 'image0',
originalname: 'Some_Image_Name.jpg',
encoding: '7bit',
mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
destination: 'images',
filename: '28efd1e7544820acc0ac174ac8404ea9.jpg',
path: 'images\\28efd1e7544820acc0ac174ac8404ea9.jpg',
size: 109205 }
```

Which is an object.

You can access the property `fieldname` from this object.